# Delete key doesn't work properly in PHP interactive shell

Tags: shell, php, gnome-terminal

In the interactive shell oh PHP <kbd>Delete</kbd> key is not working and produce `~` instead. Anyone know how to get this key to work? I am using Ubuntu 13.04 if this does matter.

Comment: have you tried ctrl + backspace ?

Comment: @h3rrmiller Is working with Ctrl+D, but still I want to use Delete key.

Comment: Can you explain how you get to the php prompt?

Comment: Can you post the contents of either your `~/.inputrc` (if you have one), or `/etc/inputrc`

Comment: @sim From gnome-terminal with `php -a`

Comment: @Poundex : http://paste.ubuntu.com/5847928/ ; there in no `~/.inputrc` file on my system.

Comment: Post the outputs of `bash --version` and `sh --version` please.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman `bash --version`: ...`version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`...; `sh --version`: `sh: 0: Illegal option --`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running `rlwrap -a` around the PHP interactive shell? [rlwrap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) fixes many of these types of problems for me in various REPLs.

Comment: I've installed first `rlwrap` with `sudo apt-get rlwrap` and I started PHP interactive shell with `rlwrap -a php -a` and now every key and shortcut key is working like in the default bash shell. Thank you!